# Linux mencoder and green frames

Tags: mencoder

I like to rip my vhs on mpeg format
I use a vcr svhs and this mencoder line

```
mencoder -tv driver=v4l2:alsa:adevice=hw.0,0:amode=1:audiorate=32000:forceaudio:immediatemode=0:freq=189.250:device=/dev/video0:input=3:norm=PAL:width=720:height=576:outfmt=yuy2 tv:// -oac lavc -ovc lavc -of mpeg -mpegopts format=dvd -vf pp=lb/ha/va/dr,hqdn3d,harddup -srate 48000 -af lavcresample=48000 -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg2video:vrc_buf_size=1500:vrc_maxrate=8000:vbitrate=7000:keyint=15:acodec=mp2:abitrate=192:aspect=4/3 -o video.mpg
```

The rip is ok,audio in sync but i see very annoyng green frames
and actors seems aliens.
There is a way to avoid green frames?

[image]